# Get MSPID from a command line request in chaincode

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I'm currently trying to evaluate the requester MSPID to authorize a specific list of Members being able to request a function on chaincode, but when I ask for "stub.getCreator().mspId" it always give me "undefined"

I'm currently calling the function with command like via "docker exec". I checked that my transaction should be signed before to "getCreator" to work, but I don't know if it's possible to sign a transaction with a command line call.

My command line request is:

```
docker exec cli.example.com peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C examplechannel -c '{"Args":["createVcc", "{ \"date\": 12345, \"reference\": \"anything\", \"serialNumber\": \"BR-12345\", \"presentedTo\": \"Example project\", \"quantity\": 22279 }"]}' -n example
```

The validation function:

```
const isAdmin = (func, creator) => {
    if (!adminList.includes(creator)) {
        throw new Error(`Organization ${creator} does not have access to perform function ${func}`);
    }
}
```

Using validation function in chaincode:

```
async (stub, data) => {
...
        isAdmin('createVcc', stub.getCreator().mspId);
...
}
```

And I'm receiving:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"transaction returned with failure: Organization undefined does not have access to perform function createVcc"
```

I expect to "getCreator().mspid" not to be undefined, anyone knows what could solve my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below my code snippet

```
    const ClientIdentity = require('fabric-shim').ClientIdentity;

    let cid = new ClientIdentity(stub);

    let mspID = cid.getMSPID()

    let isAuthorized = false;

    if (cid.assertAttributeValue('createVcc', mspID){
        isAuthorized = true;
    }
```

Comment: @MarcosRachid Any Time buddy Happy HLF!!

Comment: i did  as given below but i gave error as 'message:"Cannot read property 'getMSPID' of undefined"'

  > > > await ctx.stub.clientIdentity.getMSPID()

Answer (score 0):

With Node chaincode (Smart Contract) you should be able to use the [Client Identity object](https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html) and then `getMSPID()` or `getID()`

If you use the New Programming Model - specifically the [fabric-contract-api](https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/fabric-contract-api.Contract.html), then this includes the Client Identity object.  Using this you can also check Attributes from the certificate allowing you more flexibility in your access control.  There is a [tutorial here](https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/tutorial-using-contractinterface.html) and the latest Fabric Samples use the New Programming Model.

You might also like to consider using the `beforeTransaction` provided with the fabric-contract-api and use this as a place to do all your access control, checking function names and "IDs".